# lever won't advance on minolta x-700

Tags: film, minolta

first time using this! My film camera lever will not advance, and I am wondering if there is anything I can do to fix it or if I have to take it somewhere?

Comment: Is there film in the camera? Or are you trying to test advancing the lever with no film?

Comment: is there a damage visible? (also on the inside where the film sits) is the film inside? and if so is it allready rolled up completely?

Comment: Did it ever advance before, given you say you are a first time user?

Comment: On an X700 it should advance, and also cock the shutter, with no film. This isn't a Voigtländer rangefinder :)

Answer (score 1):

it is VERY common with Minolta film bodies. 
I had several minoltas fail in this manner. They have fragile connections from winder to curtains. 
It is a cheap repair $75

I had this happen 3-4x, basically everytime I dropped my camera. 
It was the only aspect of Minoltas I didnt like.

Never drop a Minolta :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you checked the battery.And checked the film rewind button is not stuck down.
Before considering electrics, try smacking you hand underneath on the base plate, this can release a stuck shutter but repeated shocks will render this into a paper weight in some cases.
These cameras have capacitors in the circuitry , and like all capacitors...they eventually fail.If you are adept at soldering and disassembly , you could attempt a fix, as the repair for these can be costly.Easier to source another off ebay and use the good bits off both to make a better camera.